# Pascal Readln is restarting the PC

Tags: windows, pascal, restart

I have a problem, though it might be virus. 
In my school, when i compile pascal programms and IF there is readln on the end - the computer restarts. The OS is windows XP.

Does anyone here know something about dealing this issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly does it restart? Is it a normal Windows shutdown? A blue flash?

Comment: Yeah it's like you do the usual xp restart.

Comment: Is this happening on:
a) all PCs at school? (what about at home?)
b) any Pascal program you write with a Readln at the end?
c) for any other students writing Pascal programs with Readln at the end?

Comment: This is so freaking cool! Use Linux ;)

Comment: @Ipthnc: I use Slackware at home, but it's the school computer i can't do anything about that =(.

Comment: Naw, Linux is boring - it just works! ;)

Comment: @JMD: Not all the PCs, but most of them( 90%). b - yeah ANY pascal program with readln at the end, and also happens on other computers and other students - the same problem everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For this we need some information about the situation:

- Compiler,
- compiler version,
- compiler target?
- What does the source look like?
- What components or other libraries/techniques does the source use?

Does the application
- do graphics? (dos lowlevel graphics could be a problem, and via the videodriver touch ring 0)
- is it very low on memory and diskspace? Maybe gets out of memory and can't allocate diskspace?

Comment: This should have been a comment to the original question, since you didn't provide an answer, but asked for additional information.

Comment: Comments are unformatted and space limited for multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool! It's not easy for a user application (including a compiler) to do that.

Yes, it sounds a lot like your Pascal compiler is broken - either by a virus or just a disk copying error or such. Virus scan your PC and replace the compiler.

Comment: either that or some virus hijacked a few win32 dll that the compiled program uses...